# Como exibir os atributos de uma Exception em Python?

Tags: python, exceção

Estou fazendo alguns exercícios com exceptions criadas por mim em Python mas não entendi muito bem essa parte de atributos em exceptions. Queria que quando o código caísse na exception, ele mostrasse um determinado argumento. Como faço isso?

Answer (score 3):

Não sei se entendi direito a sua pergunta, mas classes de exceções no python podem utilizar-se dos mesmos mecanismos de construtores, atributos, propriedades e métodos que quaisquer outras classes também podem. Logo, talvez você queira fazer algo mais ou menos assim:

```
class MinhaExcecao(Exception):
    def __init__(self, valor):
        self.__valor = valor

    @property
    def valor(self):
        return self.__valor

def alguma_funcao():
    raise MinhaExcecao(42)

def outra_funcao():
    try:
        alguma_funcao()
    except MinhaExcecao as e:
        print(e.valor)

outra_funcao()
```

Observe que o `e` no bloco `except` é uma variável que contém uma referência à `MinhaExcecao`. Assim sendo, você pode utilizar todos os métodos, propriedades e atributos que `MinhaExcecao` oferece para fazer o que precisar. Em especial, isso é muito útil para transportar-se informações detalhadas sobre um erro/exceção da sua origem até o ponto onde o mesmo é tratado.

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/hYE6lQ)

Answer (score 0):

É muito simples, você pode Printar algo ou até mesmo retornar um JSON.

```
     try:
         return bla
     except Exception as ex:
         # print "Sua mensagem" # ou
         return algo
```

Veja também na documentação: 2.7 https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

ou na 3.7 https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Bom estudo!